# Angular: BehaviorSubject not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to get the current value of a BevhaviorSubject in Angular. I printed each, the whole thing and the value only, to the console to check its content by using these two lines:

```
console.log(this._isNumeric)
console.log(this._isNumeric.getValue())
```

...but what I am receiving is this:

```
closed: false
hasError: false
isStopped: false
observers: []
thrownError: null
_isScalar: false
_value: true
value: true
__proto__: Subject
```

for the subject (note that the value parameter is set to true) and

```
false
```

if I am just printing the value.  Maybe I am making an obvious mistake, but does someone has a clue how to get the actual value of the BehaviorSubject? Using `.value` instead of `.getValue()` does not change the outcome. Thank you! :)

Comment: Some things you can learn by trial and error. This is not one of them. Look up "BehaviorSubject" in your favourite search engine. TLDR the answer is `this._isNumeric.subscribe(val => { /* do something with val */})`

Comment: You can also do this._isNumeric.value, which should give you the value

Comment: You should pick an accepted answer as to help anyone else that might see this post

Answer (score 1):

Every Behavior Subject will require 3 things: a) initial value, b) a source that can be turned into an observable c) a public variable that can be subscribed. You can use Behavior Subject like this:

```
// In your service file, do this

@Injectable({ provideIn: 'root' })
export class YourServiceName {
  
  // Set the initialvalues in this format ==>
  // initialValuesForBehaviorSubject: YourModel = initialValue;
  // In your case: 
  initialValue: boolean = false;


  // Make a source using Behavior Subject as a type and above initial
  // values as the initial value as a private variable
  // This source is required to SET the data
  // Your case: 
  private behaviorSubjectSource: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = 
       new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.initialValue);

  // Create a public observable to GET the data
  // Your case: 
  observableForBehaviorSubject: Observable<boolean> = 
     this.behaviorSubjectSource.asObservable();


  // Create a method to set the data from anywhere in your application
  setData(data: boolean) {
    this.behaviorSubjectSource.next(data);
  }

  // Create a method to get data from anywhere in your application
  getData(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.observableForBehaviorSubject;
  }
}



///// In your component-a.ts file, set the value like this: 

ngOnInit() {
  this.yourService.setData(true);
}

//// In your component-b.ts, get the value like this: 

ngOnInit() {
  localVariableToStoreObservableData: boolean; 

  this.yourService.getData().subscribe(data => {
     if(data) {
       this.localVariableToStoreObservableData = data;
     }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your service you can create and expose the BehaviorSubject like this:

```
private _isNumeric$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false); // first value is false

/** Protects the _isNumeric$ BehaviorSubject from outside access */
public get IsNumeric$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._isNumeric$.asObservable();
}

// NOTE: This is how you can access the value within the service
private get IsNumeric(): boolean {
    return this._isNumeric$.getValue();
}
```

To clarify the use of the '$' at the end of the variable name. It does not do anything, it is just sometimes used by convention to indicate that a variable holds an Observable or that a function will return an Observable.

If you wanted to emit a new value you can do so using '.next()' on the BehaviorSubject

```
this._isNumeric$.next(true); // Emit a value of true
```

If you wanted to access the data from a component you can retrieve the data by subscribing to it like so. Remember to unsubscribe from the BehaviorSubject as well.

```
this.yourService.IsNumeric$
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.onDestroy$)) // This is just a subject used to unsubscribe later
  .subscribe((value: boolean) => {
    // Use the result from the BehaviorSubject
  });
```